Why "continously differentiable" in optimization results?
In many results in Optimization, the function to minimize is often required to be continuously differentiable.
For example, the 1st-order necessary condition says that

If $x^{\ast}$ is a local minimizer of $f$ and $f$ is continuously
differentiable in an open neighborhood of $x^{\ast}$, then $\nabla f(x^{\ast}) = 0$.

Why do we need this continuously differentiability assumption?
I understand that we need the differentiability assumption but why is it insufficient?
Is it possible to find a counter example  where the 1st-order necessary condition does not hold with $f$ differentiable but not continuously differentiable?
Thank you very much!

differentiability at the point $x^*$ is enough.

@peek-a-boo ok thank you! But then do you know why, in most references, we can read the need of the "continuously differentiability assumption" and not only the differentiability assumption?

The answer to that question is always that the book in question isn’t striving for maximal generality.
